Gdm.service preventing me to boot, ubuntu 24.04
I can boot all the way up till I keep getting the error of no space left on the device and then gdm.service fails, then I enter sudo to try
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop 

To fix my problem it only tells me the same no space left on the device, I have tried everything to fix this but nothing is letting me open space, Does anyone know what to do I have my schoolwork on here that needs submitting in 3 days !!!
